# How big is a block in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My 7 year old has started playing Minecraft and I'm curious as to how big in "real" measurements a block is. Would be fun to make some scale models…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about real world comparisons, not gaming.

Comment: @Frank it's gaming trivia, which you could maybe bend into being "plot", which is on-topic.

Comment: @Nick I'm having real trouble seeing how a block size can be lore. Care to elucidate?

Comment: @Frank They are asking for measurements of an in-game item, what they plan to do with that information is irrelevant. This is no different than if I asked how wide the continent of Erathia is or how far Ascalon is from Lion's Arch.

Comment: Bam, question solved: The statistics screen shows the statistics distance walked/crouched/sprinted/swum/fallen/climbed/flown/dived/by minecart/boat/pig/horse/elytra in cm/m/km, so it is an in-game measurement, therefore this question is on topic.

Comment: If you're making *scale* models, then the "real" measurements are irrelevant.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It has been well established that the length of the sides of one solid block in Minecraft is 1m, making its volume 1m³. This is supported by [Gamepedia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Units_of_measure).

The height of the player is 1.8 blocks, thus 1.80 meters.

The wiki also mentions voxels, which is kind of like a 3D pixel. Because the blocks use 16x16 textures, you could consider a voxel to be 6.25 cm on a side and to have a volume of 244 cm³.

Comment: @Zacharý I think the voxels are the equivalent cubes-of-pixels in the textures, which are 16x16 for each face of the cube? The post here misconstrues it.

Comment: Ok, to clarify it: Minecraft does not have voxels. Minecraft has blocks with 6 flat textures on them, that are 6x16x16 pixels and when you go inside, they are hollow. If it was a voxel game, there were 16x16x16 completely filled out cubes of colour and when you went inside, you would just see that colour. These are voxels: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Voxelgitter.png In general, games very rarely use voxels and Minecraft definitely doesn't. Maybe you could describe the entire block as one voxel, but that's not what the paragraph says.

Comment: This answer is slightly wrong: Minecraft **does have 1m^3 voxels**, i.e. blocks are voxels. The pixels mentioned in the wiki are just for textures. Note that voxels are not always cubic (see Space Engineers for example)

Comment: @Synxis Doesn't the size of the pixels vary? The wiki said the volume of a voxel was 244cm^3 and I assumed a voxel was like a 3D pixel of which entities are made, thus making ~6.25cm the minimum size of an entity

Comment: @JohnSmith entity texture pixels are hardly consistent. the outer layer of a helmet/hat/hair player texture, for example, has bigger pixels than the head itself. Synxis is right, the only thing that is made out of voxels in Minecraft is the world, and those voxels are the blocks, which have 1m³ volume.

Comment: @Kroltan Well then what could the wiki possibly refer to when talking about a 244cm^3 voxel?

Comment: If you are talking about the "pixels" in the texture, those are [texels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texel_(graphics)). If there is something to be called [voxels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voxel) in Minecraft, that got to be the blocks. The size of the texel depends on the resource pack. if the texture has 16 texels on the side and the block is 1 meter³, then the length of that texel is 1m/16 = 6.25 cm, then the volume of the hypothetical voxel of that size would be (6.25 cm)³ = 244.1 cm³.

Comment: How could a voxel be that size, and what have *textures* to do with it? A voxel in minecraft is 1x1x1 meter, since one voxel is one cube. How its textured has nothing to do with how its rendered, thats not how voxel engines work...

Comment: I think there are two different points of view here on what is called a "voxel" in this case: People who think that a block is completely filled and that the texture applies to a 3D space, therefore justifying a calculation of the cube of the texture pixel length and calling it a voxel. This view was apparently the one of whoever wrote that part of the wiki article. And the other side, looking at Minecraft blocks as six flat (2D) textures that have no depth at all and would therefore have nothing to do with volume calculations, here "voxel" instead refers to the entire block, because it's in

Comment: a grid of blocks that makes up the Minecraft world. This is my view. Since the textures are indeed flat, as you can see when you slowly fly at a 1° angle to their surface in gamemode 3 (there is no point where you see a width, it's just inside the block or outside), the calculation of the texture pixels in cube form has no use, because there's no in-game equivalent to this volume. You can then call the blocks "voxels", but then you just have 1m³, which has no more information for this particular question than saying that a block is 1m long.

Comment: @Fabian You are mixing the *logical* representation and the *visual* representation. A voxel in a voxel engine is a *logical* unit - in this case the 1x1x1m cube. The six sides of that cube are the *isosurface* of a single voxel. Note that if you put two blocks side by side, the faces of the two adjacent walls that are inside are never generated - the isosurface of two adjacent cubes again has 6 faces, not 12. voxel engines are not restricted to fixed grids, though, and not to cubes. You can have voxelized water where voxels can *move* and aren't fixed to a grid at all, for example.

Comment: @Fabian Which means the fact that the *faces* are flat is completely irrelevant to the question of what a voxel is - since a voxel is the logical unit, and its visual representation is its isosurface (the generated mesh). from a logical point of view, voxels are slid. from an graphics point of view, it makes sense to represent solid objects only by their slid boundaries (the enclosing mesh). *Not a single object* in any game is actually a *solid* from a graphical point of view.

Comment: That is correct. In that sense, blocks are the voxels of Minecraft. But then the volume of these voxels is 1m³ and not (1/16)³m³.

Comment: Wow, thank you everyone for your answers and information. I never realised there was so much to Minecraft! 

Answer (score 13):

According to the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Measuring_distance), Minecraft uses the metric system. Each block is 1 cubic meter.

Answer (score 2):

A block is 1 meter (approx. 3 feet), half the size of a full grown adult however if you plan on making replicas or recreations I would adjust the height for your 7 year old. (Assuming they’re shorter than about 5’5)

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about the 1 cubic meter, and if you take the avatars hight yes is 1.8 meters but if you take his with (shoulder to shoulder) is 1 meter and no one has 1 meter with shoulders.
 So I took the drowing aproche, to make a even propotional human body you can messure the head and mutiply by 8 and you can determen the ideal hight.

Example : my head mesurment is 24 cm (9.6 inches) so my ideal hight should be 192 cm (76.8 inches) but my hight is 168 cm or 7 times my head size.
 If I take these aproche and put it in minecraft, the minecraft avatars hight is only 3.5 heads, were you can draw the conclusion that hes ultra short or he has the proportions of a child.

If you agree with me that the avatar is very short/a child (to take my mesurments of 24 cm for his head, his body is 84 cm) and the conclusion can be taken that every cube is aprox (46 cm) 0.5 meters per side, 0.125 m3, or you need 4 cubes to make 1 m2, if you need to make a cubic meter you need to 8 minecraft cubes.

This is my take on it. (sorry for my bad english, i tried to make some corrections)

Answer (score -2):

If you didn't know, one block in minecraft is 1 meter in real life. So that means if something in real life is 20 meters high, you would build 20 blocks high. It's different when you are refering to other blocks such as saplings and rods,sea pickles and Turtle Eggs(In the aqua update).

Answer (score -3):

Well, Minecraft is 125 times *bigger* than Earth, so 1 block would be 1/2 the height of 1 full-grown man cubed times 125. Since the average height of a full-grown man is 70 inches, divide that by 2 (35 inches), cube that (42875 cubic inches), despite the fact that Minecraft has cubes, and multiply 42875 cubic inches by 125, which is about 5.4 million cubic inches (exactly 5359375 cubic inches)! Also, this is exact IRL (in real life) measurements. The *volume* of the planet of Minecraft is 2.6*(10^14) cubic miles, which isn't even as big as Jupiter, despite that the volume is 3.43*(10^14) cubic miles! Woah!!

Comment: That is 136128.1 IRL cubic meters!

Comment: I don't know what you're basing this on, but most "Minecraft world is bigger than Earth" assessments are based on the standard 1 meter conversion - i.e. it has many more blocks in each direction than the number of meters (20 million) in any direction on Earth, not that the blocks themselves are bigger.

Comment: Aside from this being the wrong interpretation of those external sources, your math relating to cubic measurements is off. 5.4 million in^3 is 88 m^3 (because you need to multiply by the *cube* of the inch -> meter conversion factor to convert in^3 -> m^3); and if something is "125 times bigger", either that means you should multiply by 125^3, or it would be more useful to write that as 5^3 (depending on whether that's 125 times more volume, or length).

Comment: @EthanKaminski look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jL80LeiX6TU. Then, go to https://www.google.com/search?q=square%20calc%3A%20find%20a%2C%20d%3D7.07107&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS735US736&oq=square+calc+find+s&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.4385j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&skip=s. You should see the side is rounded to 5 when rounding to nearest whole. Cube 5, and you get 125.

Comment: In the first 20 seconds of that video, it says that blocks are 1 cubic meter in size. So, that should be the starting point for calculations.